# sencha-touch width of tab panel decreases

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch

-I have a problem here
tabBarDock: 'bottom'
reduces the height of the tab panel, from default top height.
-Please help

```
Ext.setup({
icon:'icon.png',
 glossOnIcon: false,
onReady:function(){
  new Ext.TabPanel({
        fullscreen: true,
        type: 'dark',
        sortable: true,
        tabBarDock: 'bottom',
        items: [{
            title: 'Tab 1',
            html: '1',
            cls: 'card1'
        }, {
            title: 'Tab 2',
            xtype:'map',
            useCurrentLocation: true,
            fullscreen:true,
        layout:'fit',
            cls: 'card2'
        }, {
            title: 'Tab 3',
            html: '3',
            cls: 'card3'
        }]
    });
}});
```

Answer (score 0):

When the tab bar is docked to the bottom you must include a `iconCls` property in order to have get the default top height. See example:

```
Ext.setup({
icon:'icon.png',
 glossOnIcon: false,
onReady:function(){
  new Ext.TabPanel({
        fullscreen: true,
        ui: 'dark',
        sortable: true,
        tabBarDock: 'bottom',
        items: [{
            title: 'Tab 1',
            iconCls:'home',
            html: '1',
            cls: 'card1'
        }, {
            title: 'Tab 2',
            iconCls:'locate',
            xtype:'map',
            useCurrentLocation: true,
            fullscreen:true,
        layout:'fit',
            cls: 'card2'
        }, {
            title: 'Tab 3',
            html: '3',
            iconCls:'search',
            cls: 'card3'
        }]
    });
}});
```

Also the `Ext.TapPanel` doesn't have `type` property. I think you meant the `ui` property.